# Am I missing the target with exp_continue?

Tags: tcl, expect, cisco-ios

I'm trying to write an expect script that allows me to ssh into a switch, look for a certain set of software in flash, then delete it. I would like to say that if you see result "A" do action "B", and if you see result "C" do action "B". All of these results are displayed when I run one command.

This is an example of a result I'm expecting.

```
B3898_RM23_SW1#dir ?
  /all             List all files
  /recursive       List files recursively
  all-filesystems  List files on all filesystems
  bs:              Directory or file name
  cns:             Directory or file name
  flash1:          Directory or file name
  flash2:          Directory or file name
  flash:           Directory or file name
  null:            Directory or file name
  nvram:           Directory or file name
  system:          Directory or file name
  tar:             Directory or file name
  tmpsys:          Directory or file name
  vb:              Directory or file name
  xmodem:          Directory or file name
  ymodem:          Directory or file name
  <cr>

  B3898_RM23_SW1#
```

What I'm looking for is the "flash1:" directory. Now there is a possibility of their being a total of nine flash file systems. You'll always have "flash1:"; what I want to do is go into each of the possible directories and delete either a file or an entire directory. And if their is no other directories just to move on.

What I want to know is how to properly use exp_continue, or if I need to use it at all in this instance. This is what I've got written, and it will copy the software to flash1, but if flas2 and so on exist it wont copy or delete the software over to the other flashes.

```
send "dir ?\r"
expect {
    -re {\mflash1\M} {
        send "delete /force /recursive flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5\r"
        expect "*#"
        send "delete /force /recursive flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash2\M} {
        send "delete /force /recursive flash2:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5\r"
        expect "*#"
        send "delete /force /recursive flash2:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r"
        expect "*#" 
        }
    -re {\mflash3\M} {
        send "delete /force /recursive flash3:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5\r"
        expect "*#"
        send "delete /force /recursive flash3:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash4\M} {
        send "delete /force /recursive flash4:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5\r"
        expect "*#"
        send "delete /force /recursive flash4:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash5\M} {
        send "delete /force /recursive flash5:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5\r"
        expect "*#"
        send "delete /force /recursive flash5:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {mflash6\M} {
        send "delete /force /recursive flash6:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5\r"
        expect "*#"
        send "delete /force /recursive flash6:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash7\M} {
        send "delete /force /recursive flash7:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5\r"
        expect "*#"
        send "delete /force /recursive flash7:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash8\M} {
        send "delete /force /recursive flash8:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5\r"
        expect "*#"
        send "delete /force /recursive flash8:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash9\M} {
        send "delete /force /recursive flash9:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5\r"
        expect "*#"
        send "delete /force /recursive flash9:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
}

#This deletes the IOS from a single device, then tftps the IOS to flash. If the TFTP fails it tries one more time.

send "copy tftp: flash1:\r"
expect "Address or name of remote host []?"
send "204.208.204.209\r"
expect "Source filename []?"
send "c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin\r"
expect "Destination filename"
send "\r"
expect {
    -re {\mtimed out\M} {
        send "copy tftp: flash:\r"
        expect "Address or name of remote host []?"
        send "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\r"
        expect "Source filename []?"
        send "c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin\r"
        expect "Destination filename [c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin]?"
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mOK - 13010154 bytes\M}
}


# checks to see if there are other members in the stack, and if there are it will copy the ios from flash1 to the other devices.

send "dir ?\r"
expect {
    -re {\mflash\M} {
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash1\M} {
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash2\M} {
        send "copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin flash2:\r"
        expect "Destination filename"
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash3\M} {
        send "copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin flash3:\r"
        expect "Destination filename"
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash4\M} {
        send "copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin flash4:\r"
        expect "Destination filename"
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash5\M} {
        send "copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin flash5:\r"
        expect "Destination filename"
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash6\M} {
        send "copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin flash6:\r"
        expect "Destination filename"
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash7\M} {
        send "copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin flash7:\r"
        expect "Destination filename"
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash8\M} {
        send "copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin flash8:\r"
        expect "Destination filename"
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
    -re {\mflash9\M} {
        send "copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin flash9:\r"
        expect "Destination filename"
        send "\r"
        expect "*#"
        }
}
```

Here is the output from the script when I pipe it to a file... I'm only capturing the first loop.

```
send: sending "dir ?\r" to { exp7 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '\m(flash[1-9])\M' is 'flash?'. Activating booster.

expect: does "\r\n    6  -rwx       28612  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  config.text.backup\r\n    5  -rwx        1276   Mar 1 1993 01:04:41 +01:00  vlan.dat\r\n    4  -rwx        2404  Jun 17 2013 14:01:30 +02:00  private-config.text\r\n   88  -rwx        2404  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  private-config.text.backup\r\n    8  -rwx       43535  Jun 17 2013 14:01:29 +02:00  config.text\r\n\r\n32514048 bytes total (19417088 bytes free)\r\nB3762_6D205C_SW1&2#" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression "\m(flash[1-9])\M"? Gate "flash?"? gate=no
"*#"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "\r\n    6  -rwx       28612  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  config.text.backup\r\n    5  -rwx        1276   Mar 1 1993 01:04:41 +01:00  vlan.dat\r\n    4  -rwx        2404  Jun 17 2013 14:01:30 +02:00  private-config.text\r\n   88  -rwx        2404  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  private-config.text.backup\r\n    8  -rwx       43535  Jun 17 2013 14:01:29 +02:00  config.text\r\n\r\n32514048 bytes total (19417088 bytes free)\r\nB3762_6D205C_SW1&2#"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n    6  -rwx       28612  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  config.text.backup\r\n    5  -rwx        1276   Mar 1 1993 01:04:41 +01:00  vlan.dat\r\n    4  -rwx        2404  Jun 17 2013 14:01:30 +02:00  private-config.text\r\n   88  -rwx        2404  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  private-config.text.backup\r\n    8  -rwx       43535  Jun 17 2013 14:01:29 +02:00  config.text\r\n\r\n32514048 bytes total (19417088 bytes free)\r\nB3762_6D205C_SW1&2#"
send: sending "copy tftp: flash:\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Address or name of remote host ?"? no
d
expect: does "d" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Address or name of remote host ?"? no
i
expect: does "di" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Address or name of remote host ?"? no
r
expect: does "dir" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Address or name of remote host ?"? no

expect: does "dir " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Address or name of remote host ?"? no
?
expect: does "dir ?" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Address or name of remote host ?"? no

  /all             List all files
  /recursive       List files recursively
  all-filesystems  List files on all filesystems
  bs:              Directory or file name
  cns:             Directory or file name
  flash1:          Directory or file name
  flash2:          Directory or file name
  flash:           Directory or file name
  null:            Directory or file name
  nvram:           Directory or file name
  system:          Directory or file name
  tar:             Directory or file name
  tmpsys:          Directory or file name
  vb:              Directory or file name
  xmodem:          Directory or file name
  ymodem:          Directory or file name
  <cr>

B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#dir 
expect: does "dir ?\r\n  /all             List all files\r\n  /recursive       List files recursively\r\n  all-filesystems  List files on all filesystems\r\n  bs:              Directory or file name\r\n  cns:             Directory or file name\r\n  flash1:          Directory or file name\r\n  flash2:          Directory or file name\r\n  flash:           Directory or file name\r\n  null:            Directory or file name\r\n  nvram:           Directory or file name\r\n  system:          Directory or file name\r\n  tar:             Directory or file name\r\n  tmpsys:          Directory or file name\r\n  vb:              Directory or file name\r\n  xmodem:          Directory or file name\r\n  ymodem:          Directory or file name\r\n  <cr>\r\n\r\nB3762_6D205C_SW1&2#dir " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Address or name of remote host ?"? no


expect: does "dir ?\r\n  /all             List all files\r\n  /recursive       List files recursively\r\n  all-filesystems  List files on all filesystems\r\n  bs:              Directory or file name\r\n  cns:             Directory or file name\r\n  flash1:          Directory or file name\r\n  flash2:          Directory or file name\r\n  flash:           Directory or file name\r\n  null:            Directory or file name\r\n  nvram:           Directory or file name\r\n  system:          Directory or file name\r\n  tar:             Directory or file name\r\n  tmpsys:          Directory or file name\r\n  vb:              Directory or file name\r\n  xmodem:          Directory or file name\r\n  ymodem:          Directory or file name\r\n  <cr>\r\n\r\nB3762_6D205C_SW1&2#dir \r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Address or name of remote host ?"? no
Directory of flash:/

    2  -rwx        9240  Jun 17 2013 14:01:30 +02:00  multiple-fs
    3  -rwx    13006601  Apr 24 2012 19:24:08 +02:00  c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin
    6  -rwx       28612  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  config.text.backup
    5  -rwx        1276   Mar 1 1993 01:04:41 +01:00  vlan.dat
    4  -rwx        2404  Jun 17 2013 14:01:30 +02:00  private-config.text
   88  -rwx        2404  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  private-config.text.backup
    8  -rwx       43535  Jun 17 2013 14:01:29 +02:00  config.text

32514048 bytes total (19417088 bytes free)
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#
expect: does "dir ?\r\n  /all             List all files\r\n  /recursive       List files recursively\r\n  all-filesystems  List files on all filesystems\r\n  bs:              Directory or file name\r\n  cns:             Directory or file name\r\n  flash1:          Directory or file name\r\n  flash2:          Directory or file name\r\n  flash:           Directory or file name\r\n  null:            Directory or file name\r\n  nvram:           Directory or file name\r\n  system:          Directory or file name\r\n  tar:             Directory or file name\r\n  tmpsys:          Directory or file name\r\n  vb:              Directory or file name\r\n  xmodem:          Directory or file name\r\n  ymodem:          Directory or file name\r\n  <cr>\r\n\r\nB3762_6D205C_SW1&2#dir \r\nDirectory of flash:/\r\n\r\n    2  -rwx        9240  Jun 17 2013 14:01:30 +02:00  multiple-fs\r\n    3  -rwx    13006601  Apr 24 2012 19:24:08 +02:00  c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r\n    6  -rwx       28612  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  config.text.backup\r\n    5  -rwx        1276   Mar 1 1993 01:04:41 +01:00  vlan.dat\r\n    4  -rwx        2404  Jun 17 2013 14:01:30 +02:00  private-config.text\r\n   88  -rwx        2404  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  private-config.text.backup\r\n    8  -rwx       43535  Jun 17 2013 14:01:29 +02:00  config.text\r\n\r\n32514048 bytes total (19417088 bytes free)\r\nB3762_6D205C_SW1&2#" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Address or name of remote host ?"? no
c
```

Here's an example of what it would look like if I ran all of those commands manually.

```
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#term length 0
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#wr
Building configuration...
[OK]
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#dir flash:
# This first DIR tells me whether or not I have .bin version 5 or version 7. If I have version 7 I exit out of the script and I move on to upgrading another device. If it has version 5 continue on through the script.
Directory of flash:/

    3  -rwx    13006601  Apr 24 2012 19:24:08 +02:00  c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin
    6  -rwx       28612  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  config.text.backup
    5  -rwx        1276   Mar 1 1993 01:04:41 +01:00  vlan.dat
    4  -rwx        9240  Jun 18 2013 07:44:01 +02:00  multiple-fs
    7  -rwx       43535  Jun 18 2013 07:44:01 +02:00  config.text
   88  -rwx        2404  Apr 23 2012 02:35:18 +02:00  private-config.text.backup
    8  -rwx        2404  Jun 18 2013 07:44:01 +02:00  private-config.text

32514048 bytes total (19417088 bytes free)
# This dir tells me how many flash file systems there are. I want to use this output to determine how many flash file systems I have to delete the old version 5 .bin file from.
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#dir ?
  /all             List all files
  /recursive       List files recursively
  all-filesystems  List files on all filesystems
  bs:              Directory or file name
  cns:             Directory or file name
  flash1:          Directory or file name
  flash2:          Directory or file name
  flash:           Directory or file name
  null:            Directory or file name
  nvram:           Directory or file name
  system:          Directory or file name
  tar:             Directory or file name
  tmpsys:          Directory or file name
  vb:              Directory or file name
  xmodem:          Directory or file name
  ymodem:          Directory or file name
  <cr>

B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#delete /force /recursive flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#delete /force /recursive flash2:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#copy tftp: flash:
Address or name of remote host []? 204.208.204.209
Source filename []? c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin
Destination filename [c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin]?
Accessing tftp://204.208.204.209/c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin...
Loading c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin from 204.208.204.209 (via Vlan402): !OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!O!OO!OO!OO!OOO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!O!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO!OO
[OK - 13010154 bytes]

13010154 bytes copied in 281.312 secs (46248 bytes/sec)
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#dir ?
# I want to use this "dir ?" to tell me I how many flash file systems I have to copy the new version 7 flash file system to. 
  /all             List all files
  /recursive       List files recursively
  all-filesystems  List files on all filesystems
  bs:              Directory or file name
  cns:             Directory or file name
  flash1:          Directory or file name
  flash2:          Directory or file name
  flash:           Directory or file name
  null:            Directory or file name
  nvram:           Directory or file name
  system:          Directory or file name
  tar:             Directory or file name
  tmpsys:          Directory or file name
  vb:              Directory or file name
  xmodem:          Directory or file name
  ymodem:          Directory or file name
  <cr>
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin flash2:
Destination filename [c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin]?
Copy in progress...CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
13010154 bytes copied in 171.731 secs (75759 bytes/sec)
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2(config)#boot system switch all flash:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2(config)#exit
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#reload at 02:00 22 June

System configuration has been modified. Save? [yes/no]: yes
Building configuration...
[OK]
Reload scheduled for 02:00:00 CEST Sat Jun 22 2013 (in 90 hours and 3 minutes) by super.poop on vty0 (204.208.XXX.XXX)
Proceed with reload? [confirm]
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#term length 50
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#wr mem
Building configuration...
[OK]
B3762_6D205C_SW1&2#exit
```

This is the only section that's failing right now!

```
set DIR {flash2 flash3 flash4 flash5 flash6 flash7 flash8 flash9}
send "dir ?\r"
expect {
    -re {\m(flash[2-9])\M} {
        lappend DIR $expect_out(1,string)
        exp_continue
    }
    "*#"
}
foreach X $DIR {
    send "copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin $X:\r"
    expect "Destination filename"
    send "\r"
    expect "*#"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say:

```
set flash_dirs {}
send "dir ?\r"
expect {
    -re {\m(flash[1-9])\M} {
        lappend flash_dirs $expect_out(1,string)
        exp_continue
    }
    "*#"
}
foreach dir $flash_dirs {
    send "delete /force /recursive $dir:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5\r"
    expect "*#"
    send "delete /force /recursive $dir:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE5.bin\r"
    expect "*#"
}
```

Then you copy stuff into flash1. After that, I assume the dir list has not changed, so you already know which flash drives are mounted:

```
foreach dir $flash_dirs {
    if {$dir eq "flash1"} continue
    send "copy flash1:c3750-ipservicesk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin $dir:\r"
    expect "Destination filename"
    send "\r"
    expect "*#"
}
```

Much [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)er. Untested of course.

Comment: so for some reason, it's doing a dir flash: (flash and flash1 are the same directory by the way, the only reason it's numbered is to identify which switch you're working on in the stack). It's not deleting the old .bin file, or copying the new .bin file to other members of the stack.

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` to the top of your script. Expect will show you what's going on.

Comment: It just keeps repeating the "dir ?" withouth actually looking for any of the numbered flash directories i.e. flash2, flash3, etc... I've managed to pipe the output from the exp_internal into a file. Is there a way to post it up here, or should I just edit my original post and put it up there?

Comment: Reading through it, it looks like nothing is matching the regular expression.

Comment: In the expect debug output, the first "dir ?" you send results in an actual file listing. Were you expecting to see the flash keywords there?

Comment: When I do the first "dir ?" this will tell me how many flash file systems are available. If you look at the example I provided there are two flash1: and flash2:. I'm trying to take output of this list and use it to determine whether or not I need to delete an old .bin file, and copy the new one after I tftp it over to flash1:.

Comment: I put an example up of what it would look like if I ran all of the commands in my script manually. I put a copy of the script up as well.

Comment: Why is there no list defined when we define the variable flash_dirs? The brackets are just empty. Should I populate that with a list of the flash directories, or the regular expression \m(flash[1-9])\M

Comment: That's just declaring the variable to be an empty list. The first expect command is *supposed* to populate it.

Comment: When I define the list with the variable the first loop works just fine. So for some reason the regular expression isn't populating the variable even though it's seeing the desired output.

Comment: Maybe you should use `script` to capture the whole session, and post a link to the result.

Comment: I could email it to you, but the results are too large to post here and I don't know where else I would post them.

Comment: I posted the section that's failing right now in my initial post. It's under "This is the only section that's failing right now!" It will copy from flash1 to flash2, but flash3 doesn't exist. That's when the script fails. What do I do if there are a potential for nine flash file systems? How do I tell expect that if flash X doesn't exist continue on?